# problem with dataset dbplyr :: nycflights13

Tags: r

What am I miss here? Please let me know.

The downloaded binary packages are in

```
/var/folders/tr/5c6z01mn2hz9z0xzznl447l80000gn/T//Rtmp33D2NT/downloaded_packages
> library(dbplyr)
> install.packages("nycflights13")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("nycflights13")
Installing package into ‘/Users/shilpu/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/nycflights13_1.0.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4502809 bytes (4.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.3 MB
```

The downloaded binary packages are in

```
/var/folders/tr/5c6z01mn2hz9z0xzznl447l80000gn/T//Rtmp33D2NT/downloaded_packages
> library(nycflights13)
> data(nycflights13)
Warning message:
In data(nycflights13) : data set ‘nycflights13’ not found
```

Comment: Try [`data(flights, package = "nycflights13")`](https://github.com/tidyverse/nycflights13).

Comment: Can you say what didn't work? I have just checked again and as long as package `"nycflights13"` is installed the instruction above loads data set `flights`. You don't have o load a package to load one of its data sets, that's why I have suggested `data(flights, package = "nycflights13")`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone....i figured it out with all your support and guidences. I did the same.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `nycflights13` is the name of the package, not the dataset. In the github page, the docs describe 5 datasets: `flights` , `weather`, `planes`, `airports` and `airlines`. Maybe you should try `data(flights)` instead?